# Configure google apps account as identity provider

Tags: php, saml-2.0

Any idea how to SAML 2.0/Openid authentication using simplesamlphp against google apps accounts as identity provide to my service?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the normal SAML metadata procedure - swapping idp.xml / sp.xml metadata.

Refer: [Setting up a simpleSAMLphp SAML 2.0 IdP to use with Google Apps for Education](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.5/simplesamlphp-googleapps).